# Python Socket client recv (buffer size)

Tags: python, sockets, client, recv

I am trying to write server response to a text file using python socket programing though my code works it is not writing line by line (i.e) i need to append current time in end of each line data,but it is printing in second line

Your help is greatly appreciated!!!

Server side: ping www.google.com | nc -l 9000

client side :

```
   PORT = 9000
   HOST = 127.0.0.1
   client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   client.connect((self.HOST,self.PORT))
   with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
       while (recieved_data < self.BUFFER_SIZE):
            try:
                data = client.recv(self.BUFFER_SIZE)
                recieved_data += len(data)
                f.write(data + ' ' + ip_port_details + ' ' + str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%Y%m%y%I%M%S')))
                print 'recieved_data',recieved_data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's because `ping` already sends data with newlines, `\n`. Or `ip_port_details` ends with the same newline symbol `\n`. You can whether remove trailing newlines via `data.strip('\n')` or split your incoming data in a list of strings via `data.split('\n')` and append a timestamp to each string. Alternatively, you can replace all newlines with something:

```
>>> 'abc\nd123'.replace('\n', '<newline>')
'abc<newline>123'
```

Comment: it works, thanks for your time and answer @Vovanrock2002